# Subtyping polymorphism: Always late binding?

Tags: java, polymorphism, late-binding, static-binding

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding#Binding_time) wikipedia states:

> Since the specific type of a polymorphic object is not known before
>   runtime (in general), the executed function is dynamically bound.
>   Take, for example, the following Java code:
>
> ```
>  public void foo(java.util.List<String> list) {
>      list.add("bar");  
>  }
> ```
>
> List is an interface, so list must refer to a subtype of it. Is it a
>   reference to a LinkedList, an ArrayList, or some other subtype of
>   List? The actual method referenced by add is not known until runtime.

Consider this example:

```
List<String> list;

list = new LinkedList<String>();
foo(list);

list = new ArrayList<String>();
foo(list);
```

Why is the actual method referenced here is not know until runtime? Couldn't the compiler just check for each call of foo of which type the object *list* is assigned to? Of course this would be only possible if the program is deterministic and no randomness is involved (e.g. user interaction).

Is this what *(in general)* in the quoted statement is about or is my understanding wrong?

In the special case when the program is deterministic, is static binding used or is - in Java - always dynamic binding used, regardless of what is possible? If so, why?

Comment: It *could*, but that would be a lot of work for not much gain.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, the gain is great and outweights the a lot of work, thus it actually does this!

Answer (score 2):

The statement speaks about the **general** case. Given only the code of the Wikipedia example it is not possible to tell the concrete type of the `list` parameter. In your example it is possible to tell the concrete types.

The Java runtime is allowed and does in fact devirtualize method calls if it can detect the concrete type of a variable.

If you are interested in the topic: Here is a [link](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~ckrintz/papers/devirt-ibmjit.pdf) to paper which discusses devirtualization techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The devirtualization is not preformed during the compilation of java source to java bytecode. Otherwise this would be quite fragile. Note that compiled java classes usually preserve binary compatibility (with some known exceptions). Thus if your `foo` is located in the separate class and you recompile just this class, then the class calling `foo` should work with new code without recompilation.

However the devirtualization is possible at runtime and actually performed by most of modern JVMs (including Oracle HotSpot JVM, or course). This method is likely to be fully inlined during the JIT-compilation: both `foo` calls, `LinkedList.add` and `ArrayList.add` methods will be merged into the body of caller method.

So in general Wikipedia quote is correct: The actual method referenced by `add` is not known until runtime. However this does not mean that the call remains polymorphic as JVM runtime is quite complex thing which includes interpreter, JIT-compilation and execution of JIT-compiled code.